# Get all active posts that are tied to a custom taxonomy for a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, loop, taxonomy

I need to display all the categories I created for a custom post type then inside of each category I need to loop all the posts that are tied to that category.

I tried constructing my WP_Query a number of different ways and I can't get it to work at all.

Here's the code I have now:

```
$categories = get_categories('taxonomy=faqcat&order=DESC');
foreach ($categories as $cat) {

    // loop through all  posts tied to category here
}
```

Updated Code.. still doesn't work.. keeps displaying the same posts in each category.

```
<?php
$categories = get_categories('taxonomy=faqcat&order=DESC');
foreach ($categories as $cat) :

    echo '<h1>' . $cat->name . ' (' . $cat->cat_ID . ' )</h1>';
    $q = new WP_Query(array('cat_ID' => $cat->cat_ID, 'post_type' => 'faq', 'tax_query' => array('taxonomy' => 'faqcat')));
    if ($q->have_posts()) : while ($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();
      echo $post->ID;      

    ?>
            <pre> <B><?php the_title(); ?></b></pre>
            <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
            <br/>
        <?php endwhile;
    else:
        ?>
        <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
    <?php
    endif;
endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: This is a recursively confusing question.

Comment: Please do not hide your code on a third party site. It is and should be part of your question, so later readers can understand what the problem was and if it can help them with their problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I fixed it..

```
    <!--faq page -->
    <div class="faq">
        <?php get_template_part('./template/global/breadcrumbs'); ?>
        <h3><span><?php the_title(); ?></span></h3>
        <?php
        $categories = get_categories('taxonomy=faqcat&order=DESC');
        foreach ($categories as $cat) {
            $i = 0;
            ?>
            <div class="faq-title">
                <h2><?php echo $cat->name; ?></h2>
            </div>
            <?php
            $answers = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'faq', 'tax_query' => array(array('taxonomy' => 'faqcat', 'field' => 'id', 'terms' => $cat->term_id,),),));
            if ($answers->have_posts()) : while ($answers->have_posts()) : $answers->the_post();
                    $i++;
                    ?>
                    <div class="faq-post" id="faq-<?php echo $i; ?>"> <span class="close-tab"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                        <div class="faq-post-detail">
                            <?php the_content(); ?>  
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <?php
                endwhile;
            else:
                ?>
                <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
            <?php endif;
        }
        ?>





    </div>

</div>
<!--/content -->
```